# Error Executing Maven - Non-parseable settings settings.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

I'm new to Maven. I have converted my Cucumber project to Maven and I'm getting execution error when I try to run Maven Clean or Maven Build.

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-parseable settings C:\Users\qz\.m2\settings.xml: end tag name </settings> must match start tag name <activeProfiles> from line 10 (position: TEXT seen ...</pluginManagement>   \r\n</build>\r\n</settings>... @21:12)  @ C:\Users\qz\.m2\settings.xml, line 21, column 12
```

Snap of [Maven Installation and Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPU5l.png)
My settings.xml file have some problem too as under Eclipse > Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings, I can see an error 'Could not read settings.xml'

I have tried deleting my repository folder and rebuilding it but that wasn't effective. It may be something to do with my Eclipse-Maven integration.

Edit-1: adding settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

 <localRepository>Users/qz/.m2/repository</localRepository>
 <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
 <offline>false</offline>
  <profiles><profiles/>
  <activeProfiles><activeProfiles/>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>           
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>   
</build>
</settings>
```

Edit-2: corrected .xml and updated the error message

Comment: Did you check the physical file that maven is complaining about (`C:\Users\qz\.m2\settings.xml`)? Does it contain valid xml?

Comment: Hi @ernest_k, yes the file is present under the location. I have just added it too.

Comment: Your `xml` is invalid. On this line: `<localRepository>Users/qz/.m2/repository<localRepository/>`, `<localRepository/>` should be `</localRepository>`

Comment: Well spotted @ernest_k! I missed it some how. I have corrected it and the error is slightly different now. I have updated that too

Comment: `<profiles><profiles/>`, and `<activeProfiles><activeProfiles/>` have the same problem

Comment: Sorry, I have just removed them and it's a BUILD SUCCESS. Thanks again @ernest_k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close xml tag should be `</tagName>`

```
  <localRepository>Users/qz/.m2/repository 
 </localRepository>
 <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
```

You can have empty tag in single tag as `<tagName/>` or you can remove it

```
   <activeProfiles/>
```